# Creating a specific Number of agents with a determined parameter value out of 3 values

Tags: class, parameters, anylogic, agent

I need to create an agent with a parameter *"Class"* that has 3 possible values. I need to be able to determine the number of agents with each class value at the Simulation screen before the simulation starts, by using a slider that determines the number of Agents.Class=="A", Agents.Class=="B" and so on.

I've tried creating an action chart that uses RandomTrue to assign the class.

The inputs for this action chart are:

1. A parameter sums the output of the 3 sliders to determine the total n of agents
2. Another parameter computes the percentage of agents.class=="A" from the total n of agents
3. A third parameter computes the percentage of the agents.class="B" from the remaining n of agents (n-agents.class=="A")

I'm not allowed to post pictures yet, but see action chart [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdUu2.png) .

The issue with this is that when using percentages, it will round here or there and the actual number of agents with desired class may have one more or one less.

How can I make this with an exact number of agents created with each class?

Answer (score 0):

This does not make sense mathematically. If you create 10 agents and the random number splits it using 0.66 and 0.33, then you cannot create 6.66 agents.

So some rounding must happen, unless you create infinite agents.

However, you can decide to round the random number. If you know you will create 100 agents, you could use `Math.ceil(uniform(0, randomA)*100.)` or similar. If `randomA` would be 0.66666, you would get 67 as a result.

(`Math.floor` would give you 66)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me why you're converting the number to %-ages at all? Are you going to create N agents in total? If so you can just use amounts for class 'A' and class 'B' agents in two separate **Source** objects (one for each class) to create the agents at the start.